# Why index out of bounds exception when adding two 2D arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to add two matrices together and return a new matrix. Example:

```
matrixAdd({{1, 2, 3}, {4, 4, 4}}, {{5, 5, 6}, {0, -1, 2}})
```

is expected to return:

```
{{6, 7, 9}, {4, 3, 6}}
```

I can't understand why my code generates index out of bounds exception... Btw, arrays passed as parameters will always have the same dimensions so i don't need to worry about that.

```java
public static int[][] matrixAdd(int[][] a, int[][] b) {
    int[][] matrix = new int[a.length][b.length];
    for (int r = 0; r < a.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < a[r].length; c++) {
            matrix[r][c] = a[r][c] + b[r][c];
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you use `b.length` as in `matrix` creation.

That means for your data it's like

```java
int[][] matrix = new int[2][2];
```

but you need

```java
int[][] matrix = new int[2][3];
```

You can use something like this

```java
int[][] matrix = new int[a.length][a[0].length];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem

```java
int[][] matrix = new int[a.length][b.length];
```

Matrix a and b both are of size 2X3. So new matrix created by them will also be of size 2X3. But declared matrix *matrix* is of size 2X2 as a.length & b.length both returns 2.

As you have mentioned dimension of matrix is always same, you can do following.

```java
int[][] matrix = new int[2][3];
```

If it is dynamic then do following

```java
int[][] matrix = new int[a.length][a[0].length];
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now i understand my error - i initialized the column length after the row length, but i needed to initialize the column length after the column length with b[0].length (or a[0].length).

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```java
public static int[][] matrixAdd(int[][] a, int[][] b) {
    int[][] matrix = new int[a.length][b[0].length];
    for (int r = 0; r < a.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < a[r].length; c++) {
            matrix[r][c] = a[r][c] + b[r][c];
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```